# Rails Filtering Best-Practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a web app that has the following models: Shifts, Years, Checkouts, Sales and Visitors.

A Shift has_many Checkouts, Sales, Visitors
A Year has_many Shifts

Checkouts, Sales and Visitors belong_to Shift
Shifts belong_to Year

In my app, I want to have many different years present, although only ONE is active at any given time. When I display Shifts, for example, I only want Shifts from the active year to be displayed. That's easy enough.

What I'm having a real hard time with is writing a query to get all of the checkouts from the active year. Is there a simple way to go about doing this? The active year is actually set in a session variable called session[:current_year_id]. I thought the best way to go about doing it would be to do something like:

```
@checkouts = Shift.where('year_id = ?',session[:current_year_id]).checkouts
```

But that's not working for me. What do I need to change to get that to work?

Note that checkouts, sales and visitors DO NOT have their own year_id. They have a year_id through the shift that they belong to.

**Resolved:**

I upvoted all the answers, since all helped. I used the for_year lambda expression. I've upvoted all the answers.

The final answer was to use:

```
Shift.for_year(session[:current_year_id]).collect{ |shift| shift.checkouts }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.where` returns a relation, so there are two possible answers based on your intention.

If you want to find the checkouts belonging to the **first** shift, do:

```
@checkouts = Shift.where('year_id = ?',session[:current_year_id]).first.checkouts
```

If you want **all** checkouts for **all** shifts, do:

```
@checkouts = Shift.where('year_id = ?',session[:current_year_id]).collect{|shift| shift.checkouts}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a scope in Shift model that takes current year as parameter:

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :checkouts
   scope :for_year, lambda { |current_year_id| where('year_id = ?', current_year_id) }
end
```

and in the controller, you can get the checkouts for current year by chaining to the scope:

```
Shift.for_year(session[:current_year_id]).map(&:checkouts)
```

Comment: I keep getting an error that says "NoMethodError: undefined method 'checkouts' for <#ActiveRecord:Relation"

Comment: I can only run .checkouts or .sales, etc on a SINGLE shift item, not a collection of shifts.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Shift.find_all_by_year_id(session[:current_year_id])
```

This assumes `current_year_id` is in the session.

I have had problems with using `.where`, which I fixed by using a dynamic finder.

Comment: I still can't get the list of all checkouts/sales/questions/visitors from that, though. I want to know how to be able to tack on .checkouts at the end of that statement and get a collection of all the checkouts